# What are some books, websites, etc. where I can find the detailed protocol for standardization of sodium thiosulfate with dichromate?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, reference-request, books

I am looking for a book or website such as "Vogel's Textbook of Quantitative Chemical Analysis" where I can find methods for analyzing/standardizing a particular species easily.

I am not looking for an exact sub area such as water analysis or drug analysis; rather I want a resource like Vogel's which indexes generic analytical methods, both classical and modern.

Edit:
Actually I am looking for the method of standardizing a sodium thiosulfate solution using a potassium dichromate solution. I can't find the method in "Vogel's Textbook of Quantitative Chemical Analysis 6th Edition".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the book I was looking for. The method is listed in "Vogel's Textbook of Chemical Analysis 5th Edition" (page 392). They have removed it from the 6th edition.

Answer (score 3):

My go-to for this is typically Kolthoff & Sandell's [Textbook of Quantitative Inorganic Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000TCD3YE).  They unfortunately do not report a detailed protocol for dichromate standardization of thiosulfate solutions therein, but instead cite *Volumetric Analysis, Vol III* by Kolthoff and Stenger ([Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A9YOLEI) and [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=KjGNQgAACAAJ&dq=kolthoff%20and%20stenger&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0p9UVcODOsWmNrSygdgB&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ)).  I don't have access to this volume; [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/volumetric-analysis/oclc/344117&referer=brief_results) shows numerous copies in university libraries in my area of the U.S.; more than likely there's a library where you are that has a copy.

Comment: @chemkatku Sure! I was rather surprised that K&S didn't have it in detail. It must be that authors are either considering it an obsolete method, or so commonplace that it's not needed to include any more.

Answer (score 2):

**Book:**

I can find one book which should have analytical methods for most of the species.

[Encyclopedia of Separation Science](http://store.elsevier.com/product.jsp?isbn=9780122267703)

It is ten volume set.

**websites:**

There are too many websites on internet but I will choose following two:

1. [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/)
2. Wikipedia

Comment: Thanks. Encyclopedia of Separation Science is great. But I want some resource that indexes analytical methods.